# Why does the compiler skip the for-loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, sum, stdvector

I have tried to do some practice with `vector`, and I made a simple `for` loop to calculate the sum of the elements within the vector. The program did not behave in the way I expect, so I try to run a debugger, and to my surprise, somehow, the compiler skips the `for` loop altogether, and I have not come up with a reasonable explanation.

```
//all code is written in cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int simplefunction(vector<int>vect)
{
   int size = vect.size();
   int sum = 0;
   for (int count = 0; count == 4; count++) //<<--this for loop is being skipped when I count==4
   {            
      sum = sum + vect[count];
   }
   return sum;  //<<---the return sum is 0 
}

int main()
{
   vector<int>myvector(10);
   for (int i = 0; i == 10; i++)
   {
      myvector.push_back(i);
   }
   int sum = simplefunction(myvector);
   cout << "the result of the sum is " << sum;    
   return 0;

}
```

I have done some research, and usually the ill-defined `for` loop shows up when the final condition cannot be met (Ex: when setting `count--` instead of `count++`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop's conditions are wrong, as they are always `false`!

Look at to the loops there

```
for (int i = 0; i == 10; i++) 
//              ^^^^^^^-----> condition : is it `true` when i is 0 (NO!!)
```

and

```
for (int count=0; count==4; count++)
//                ^^^^^^^^^-----> condition : is it `true` when i is 0 (NO!!)
```

you are checking `i` is equal to  `10` and `4` respectively, before incrementing it. That is always `false`. Hence it has not executed further. They should be

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` and `for (int count=0; count<4; count++)`

---

Secondly, `vector<int> myvector(10);` allocates a *vector of integers* and initialized with `0` s. Meaning, the loop afterwards this line (i.e. in the `main()`)

```
for (int i = 0; i == 10; i++) {
    myvector.push_back(i);
}
```

will insert 10 more elements (i.e. `i` s) to it, and you will end up with `myvector` with `20` elements. You probably meant to do

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
myvector.reserve(10) // reserve memory to avoid unwanted reallocations
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    myvector.push_back(i);
}
```

or simpler using [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) from `<numeric>` header.

```
#include <numeric> // std::iota

std::vector<int> myvector(10);
std::iota(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 0);
```

---

As a side note, [avoid practising with `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)